# Update property of 1st class in 2nd class and get updated value in 3rd class

Tags: c#, properties, return-value

I have three classes MainWindow.xaml.cs, Download.cs and ContentFetcher.cs. Download.cs has properties set and get methods. I am updating properties of download.cs in MainWindow.xaml.cs. I want to get value of properties in Download.cs While it does not give me updated value of property.. Code of all three classes is as follow:

Download.cs

```
private int _DownloadLevel = 0;
public int DownloadLevel
{
    get { return _DownloadLevel; }
    set
    {
        if (_DownloadLevel == value)
            return;

        _DownloadLevel = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("DownloadLevel");
    }
}

private bool _IsAudio = false;
public bool IsAudio
{
    get { return _IsAudio; }
    set
    {
        if (_IsAudio == value)
            return;

        _IsAudio = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("IsAudio");
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

In ContentFetcher.cs

```
 Download download = new Download();
 MessageBox.Show(download.DownloadLevel.ToString());     // Output is 0, it should 05
 MessageBox.Show(download.IsAudio.ToString());     // Output is false while it should be true
```

Please guide me how do i get updated property values in ContentFetcher.cs

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new instance of `Download` in `ContentFetcher`. It has no reference to the values you set in the original instance, so all you get is the default value for `int`/`bool` types.

I don't see where you're instantiating `ContentFetcher`, but you need to pass in a reference to the first `Download` instance you created.

```
public class ContentFetcher
{
    Download download;

    public ContentFetcher(Download download)
    {
        this.download = download;
    }

    public void SomeOtherMethod()
    {
        // Don't create a new instance of Download - use the original instance
        // Download download = new Download();

        MessageBox.Show(download.DownloadLevel.ToString());     // Output is 0, it should 05
        MessageBox.Show(download.IsAudio.ToString());
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: I did this. Now i am getting exception. It says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: value of download is null in SomeOtherMethod while it is working good in constructor. How do i access download object in SomeOtherMethod?